# How to make line between Tree nodes using HTML, CSS & JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've recently made this tree view:

```js
const objects = document.querySelectorAll(".object");
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll(".toggler");

objects.forEach((object) => {
  object.addEventListener("click", () => {
    object.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});

togglers.forEach((toggler) => {
  toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggler.classList.toggle("active");
    toggler.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.objects {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.object::before {
  content: "\2610";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
.object.active {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #888;
}
.object.active::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
.toggler::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.toggler.active::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.toggler-target {
  display: none;
}
.toggler-target.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Standard</legend>
  <ul class="objects" id="objects">
    <li>
      <div class="toggler">Tables</div>
      <ul class="toggler-target">
        <li>
          <div class="toggler">Table 1</div>
          <ul class="toggler-target">
            <li>
              <div class="toggler">Fields</div>
              <ul class="toggler-target">
                <li class="object">Field 1</li>
                <li class="object">Field 2</li>
                <li class="object">Field 3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="toggler">Table 2</div>
          <ul class="toggler-target">
            <li>
              <div class="toggler">Fields</div>
              <ul class="toggler-target">
                <li class="object">Field 1</li>
                <li class="object">Field 2</li>
                <li class="object">Field 3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Now I want to add a visual line between the tree nodes when it expand & collapse.

[image]

If Anyone know a way how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've reach the desired result By adding these lines of *css*:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: -35px;
  background: black;
  height: 1px;
  width: 32px;
}
```